# Find an element inside a PySimpleGui's Frame by a key

Tags: python, pysimplegui

How to find an element inside a PySimpleGui's Frame by a key without hardcoding it via `.Rows[0]`?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Frame(layout=[
        [sg.Text('Field:'), sg.Text('', key='key')],
    ])]
]

window = sg.Window("Name", layout)
```

Comment: what is error in code ?? or what do you expect as output??

Comment: No error as I don't understand how to access Frame's `sg.Text('', key='key')` (without hardcoding it via `.Rows[-1]`) to fill its text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window['-KEY NAME-']` to find an element by it's key. Here is an example:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Frame(title='My Frame', layout=[
        [sg.Text('Field:'), sg.Text('', key='-KEY NAME-', size=(10, 0))]])],
    [sg.Button('Go')] 
]

window = sg.Window(title='Name', layout=layout).finalize()

window['-KEY NAME-'].update('No value set')

# MAIN LOOP
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Go':
        window['-KEY NAME-'].update('Hello World!')

window.close()
```